# Degree of splitting field of $x^6-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

> Let $f=x^6-2$, find the degree of splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I calculated the roots of $f$ are $\pm \sqrt[6]{2},\pm e^{i \pi/3}\sqrt[6]{2},\pm e^{2i \pi/3}\sqrt[6]{2}$. I suspect that the splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}(e^{i \pi/3}\sqrt[6]{2})$ but I don't know how to prove this. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The splitting field of $f$ is the field $\mathbf Q(\zeta,\sqrt[6]2)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive $6$th root of unity. The minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_6(x)=x^2-x+1$, so that
$$[\mathbf Q(\zeta):\mathbf Q]=2, \enspace[\mathbf Q(\sqrt[6]2):\mathbf Q]=6.$$
Furthermore, these extensions are linearly independent and thus
$$[\mathbf Q(\zeta\sqrt[6]2):\mathbf Q]=[\mathbf Q(\zeta):\mathbf Q][\mathbf Q(\sqrt[6]2:\mathbf Q]=12.$$

Comment: For the last 2 inequalities, is this working correct: $[Q(\zeta, \sqrt[6]2):Q]=[Q(\zeta)(\sqrt[6]2):Q]=[Q(\zeta): Q(\sqrt[6]2)][Q\sqrt[6]2):Q]=[Q(\zeta): Q][Q(\sqrt[6]2):Q]$?

Comment: It can't be correct: why should $\mathbf Q(\sqrt[6]{2})$ be a subfield of $\mathbf Q(\zeta)$?

Comment: You are right...how do I show the last 2 equalities using the linear independence?

Comment: Does one need to show something like $[Q(\zeta)(\sqrt[6]2) : Q(\sqrt[6]2)]=[Q(\zeta):Q]$

Comment: You have to show $x^6-2$ remains irreducible on $\mathbf Q(\zeta)$.

Comment: Ok got it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The splitting field of $f$ is $\mathbb{Q}(e^{i \pi/3},\sqrt[6]{2})$, which is not the same as $\mathbb{Q}(e^{i \pi/3}\sqrt[6]{2})$.

It has degree $12$ since $e^{i \pi/3}$ has degree $2$ and $\sqrt[6]{2}$ is real.